# My Paragraph won't stay on the same row as my Checkbox. What Html text element should I use with an input?

Tags: html, css

### Goal:

I want text to come after my checkbox

### Problem:

My p tag comes directly after my check box input, but I can't get them on the same line and Next to each other.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <input type="checkbox">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <p> Save My card for future payment</p>
    </div><br>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Edit:**
The best way to put ***Text*** after a checkbox or other user input button is to use a ***LABEL*** **not a p tag.**

```
<label for="check">text goes here</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="check">
```

Comment: Also (not to pile on), but don't use line breaks for spacing. Use CSS margin or padding with a class such as [mb-2](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/).

Comment: @isherwood What's the problem with using break if it works?

Comment: 1. It adds unnecessary elements (complexity) to your page. 2. It's not easily changeable via your stylesheet. 3. Bootstrap already provides the tools to space things, as I mentioned. 4. That's not what line break elements are for. They're to break lines of text. 5. "It works" isn't a good reason to do _anything_ when there's a better way. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Bootstrap as your class names suggest, this is the right way:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="defaultCheck1">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">
          Save my card for future payment
        </label>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

See the docs at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/forms/#checkboxes-and-radios.

If not, use standard checkbox markup so your form is accessible to those using assistive technology (and more standard):

```html
<label>
    <input type="checkbox">
    Save my card for future payment
</label>
```

Notice that in both cases the label is clickable.

Comment: I appreciate your frustration, but you've made a faulty assumption that I voted your question down. I did not. It's also not appropriate for you to use comments to deal with your situation. Good luck. Don't be discouraged.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your code look like that.

```css
.checkbox_div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.checkbox_div p {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkbox_div">
  <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle1" name="vehicle1" value="Bike">
  <p>Paragraph text </p>
</div>
```

If not then format your code look like that. Take checkbox input and p tag inside a div.
And then add some css which is given below.

Comment: I don't know how this is better than using the Bootstrap flex grid as initially shown (without all that custom CSS).

Comment: Also, basic checkbox markup (with the required label) does exactly this.